# Is there a viable way to make a semi-interactive command line in python

Tags: python

So i have this code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("python path/to/program.py" , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.stdout.read()
```

But the program i'm trying to execute requires user input like:

```
Press Enter to continue...
```

and

```
Would you like to do this?
(Y)es/(N)O:
```

When you try to run *program.py* in the script above, it can't put in values, and the command aborts.

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Why don't you `import` from `program.py` and use its functionality more directly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The program is a command line only script, and would need a lot of modifying and tweaking. I'd rather first know if there would be an other way